# Oracle External Tables field parsing on Linux environment

Tags: linux, parsing, oracle11g, external-tables

Stackoverflowers!

I have an issue with a Oracle Database 11g instance, where I have an External Table mapping data from an external file.

Here is my code, that is working on a development Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 virtual machine:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC (
    NAMECREDORPART1 CHAR(50 CHAR), 
    NAMECREDORPART2 CHAR(50 CHAR), 
    NAMECREDORPART3 CHAR(50 CHAR), 
    ADDRESSCREDORPART1 CHAR(50 CHAR),
    (...)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
        TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
        DEFAULT DIRECTORY FILES
        ACCESS PARAMETERS (
            records delimited by '\n' CHARACTERSET 'WE8ISO8859P15'
            LOAD WHEN (documento != blanks)
            FIELDS
            MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
            REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS (
               NAMECREDORPART1 position(1:49) char(50),
               NAMECREDORPART2 position(50:99) char(50),       
               NAMECREDORPART3 position(100:149) char(50),
               ADDRESSCREDORPART1 position(150:199) char(50),
               (...)
            )
        )
        LOCATION ('abc.mtf')
    )
PARALLEL
NOMONITORING
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

This code results on the following data being loaded/mapped on this ABC table:
[image]
This is exactly how I want my data to be loaded! :D

Unfortunelly, my Production environment is a Oracle Database 11g (same version), running on a Linux platform.
This results in a strange behavior when I use this same code, to load the same file (abc.mtf): fields get filled with spaces. I don't know why does this happen, as this is not happening on my Windows Server 2008 VM.

Here is a screenshot of this same data, on the Linux environment:

[image: http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/7535/error01i.png]

Can someone please help me getting the same output under the Linux environment as the one I get on Windows? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be the "records delimited by" clause not taking account of different end-of-line character combinations? The default NEWLINE ought to take care of that.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've tried removing these lines "records delimited by '\n' CHARACTERSET 'WE8ISO8859P15'" and "LOAD WHEN (documento != blanks)", but it had no effect. It still loads data with the spaces.